# Storing different columns from database to an array.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

heres my code.

```
$speakers=array();
    $handler2=mysql_query("SELECT fName,lName,title FROM speaker ;");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handler2)){
        $speakers[] =$row['fName'],$row['lName'],$row['title'];
        }
```

i want to get fName,lName and title from my database and store it in a single array index.

so 
`print_r($speakers)'`

will output the value of fName,lName,title like this

Array ([0]=>fname lname title [1]=>fname lname title).

can you guys help?

Comment: [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save field values as a string( *[0]=>fname lname title*) - change your code as shown below:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handler2)) {
    $speakers[] = $row['fName']. " " .$row['lName']. " " .$row['title'];
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this is exactly what i need.
wew,didnt know it was that simple, maybe my cold affected the way i think..haha

thanks @RomanPerekhrerst

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handler2)){
    $speakers[] =array($row['fName'],$row['lName'],$row['title']);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this will create multiple indexes.
not exactly what i had in mind but no worries,i found an answer.

Comment: the guy who answered after you,,

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handler2)) {
    $speakers[] = $row['fName']. " " .$row['lName']. " " .$row['title'];
}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your context you could also make MySQL do the job for you:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', title, fName, lName) as spkr FROM speaker;
```

This will only return *one* column, `spkr`, with the values already concatenated.
See [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).